# Django: html input type=input and checkbox

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox

I have a problem with send data from `input type='number'` to django view.

I have a page with products, each of them has a checkbox and a quantity selection (`input type='number'`)

```
<form action="{% url 'create-order' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-responsive table-borderless">
        <thead>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in items %}
            <tr class="align-middle alert border-bottom">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="item" value="{{ item.id }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input" min="1" value=1 type="number" name="quantity">
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="submitButton">
        <button type="submit" class="lgbtn green">Go to order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Submit button go to view:

```
def create_order(request):
    quantities = request.POST.getlist('quantity')
    items = request.POST.getlist('item')
    return JsonResponse({
        'quantities': quantities, 
        'items': items
    })
```

For example, I have 6 products with id = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. And if I choose 1, 2, 3 and set quantities: 3, 4, 5, then I get:

```
items = [1, 2, 3] # it's OK
quantities = [3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1] # but I need [3, 4, 5]
```

Ideally, I want items and quantities to be in the same object (For example `[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]` or dict `{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5}`), but not necessarily, but in any case, I need to select the quantity only for those items that have been checked

Comment: You should at least set the default quantity to 0 or empty to avoid a bunch of 1s showing up in your `quantities` list.

Comment: "Value should be greater than or equal to 1".
If I set min=0, then it will be the same as with min=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="input" min="1" value=1 type="number" name="quantity">
```

This tag basically ensures the value will be at least 1.  Try

```
   <input class="input" min="0" value=0 type="number" name="quantity">
```

For the next part you need to match the correct item with its quantity and skip if the quantity is 0 - but we also need some error checking, and to do that which have to know which quanity goes with which ID.  You can do that with something like

```
<input class="input" min="0" value=0 type="number" name="quantity-{{item.id}}">


def create_order(request):
    #get fields from the form
    items = request.POST.getlist('item')
    #create a result array to hold pairs
    result = []
    for item in items:
        quantity_name = "quantity-" + str(item)
        item_quantity = request.POST.get(quantity_name)
        if item_quantity==0:
            #handle error submitted item with 0 quantity
        else:
            result.append( (item, item_quantity) )   

    return JsonResponse({
        'result':result,
    })
```

While this won't check for unsubmitted items with positive quantities (you may need JS for that) it will behave as you'd expect a form to.

Comment: This is ok, but if I select a `checkbox with id=1`, and the `quantity is 0`, and the `checkbox with id=2` is not checked, and the `quantity is >= 1`, then it will work incorrect

Comment: Had a rethink and tried another approach.